# Using arrays to store primes

Tags: java, arrays, primes

Here is my program which is supposed to create an array and initialize prime numbers to it. The prime numbers should then be printed but the program just keeps running.

```
import java.util.*;
public class primes
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter number of primes ");
        int x = scan.nextInt();
        int[] prime = new int[x];
        int div=2,hold=2;
        int c=0;
        while (prime[x-1]==0)
        {
            for(int a=2; div>a;a++)
            {
                if(div>a && div%a==0)
                a=div;
                else if(div==(a-1))
                hold=div;
            }
            if(div==2||hold!=prime[c-1])
            {
                prime[c]=hold;
                c++;
            }
            div++;
        }
        for(int f =0; f<x;f++)
        System.out.print(" "+prime[f]+" ");
    }
}
```

I tried changing my loops but I just don't know whats wrong

Comment: How many primes do you want the program to generate?

Comment: I want it to at least be able to generate 20 primes

Comment: I suggest try changing your way of doing this, this code is a lot more confusing that it needs to be.

Comment: What algorithm did you try to implement? It's really not too easy to understand whats actually happening with your loop variables.

Comment: you while loop is going to be always true if the number you enter is bigger than 1 try 1 it should execute once. Logic is not right

Comment: (1) It appears you are in an endless loop;  prime[x-1] is always 0.  (2) appears your prime array never gets assigned any values (other than 0).  Add some log statements or System.out.println statements so you know what it's doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the others mentioned your logic is not right, try something like:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter number of primes ");
    int x = scan.nextInt();
    List<Integer> primes = getPrimes(x);
    Integer[] primeArray = primes.toArray(new Integer[primes.size()]);
    for(int i :primes.toArray(primeArray)){ // you could just use for(int i :primes){ if you don't need array
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
}

private static List<Integer> getPrimes(int upperLimit) {

    ArrayList primes = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 2; i < upperLimit; i++) {
        boolean isPrime = true;

        // Is it prime?
        for (int j = 2; j < i; j++) {
            if (i % j == 0) {
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isPrime)
            primes.add(i);
    }
    return primes;
}
```

The above will print out up to the numbers entered so if you type 5 it will print out 2 3 but not 5.

The following is an other example with Java 8, this one will print as many prime numbers based on the input, if you input 5 you will get 2 3 5 7 11

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter number of primes ");
    int x = scan.nextInt();
    long[] prime = primes(x).toArray();

    Arrays.stream(prime).forEach(value -> System.out.print(value + " " ));

}


private static LongStream primes(long max) {
    return LongStream.iterate(2, i -> i + 1)
            .filter(PrimeNumber::isPrime)
            .limit(max);
}

private static boolean isPrime(long x) {
    return LongStream.rangeClosed(2, (long)(Math.sqrt(x)))
            .allMatch(n -> x % n != 0);
}
```

Comment: Your program doesn't use any arrays and instead of returning the number of prime numbers the user inputs it instead returns all prime numbers less than the number entered.

Answer (score 0):

It will keep on running because you have this: `while (prime[x-1]==0)`. Where x is an input from the user. Say 5 for instance, then `prime[5-1]` initially is going to contain a `0` always, and you are running your while loop on this condition which is always going to turn true, thus never ending. Also, your prime number generation logic is not right!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong. First correct it, And i think you want to store prime numbers coming in range of 1 to N where N is user provided number. Use arrayList (growable) to store it.

Comment: Using  an arraylist doesn't matter here, as internally it is going to be typically the array itself. And anyway he's asking the user for the number of primes to be printed on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I  ran your code in debugger mode and I found the problem.
I tested your program with x=5.

At the end of the first while loop iteration you have :

- prime[0] = 2
- div = 3
- hold = 2
- c = 1

And here's the problem :

```
if(div==2||hold!=prime[c-1])
{
    prime[c]=hold;
    c++;
}
```

This part won't ever be reached anymore because :

- div is never decrement, so it will always be superior to 2.
- hold *is*
  equal to prime[c-1], and never change value.

So prime will always stick to be : 2 0 0 0 0, and your while loop will never end.

Answer (score 0):

I found what was wrong and rewrote the code, it works now. The program asks the user for the number primes they want to see and it prints them after storing them in a basic integer array.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Prime
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
        int i=0, hold=2, d=2;
        boolean flag = true;
        System.out.println("Enter the number of primes.");
        int[] prime= new int[scan.nextInt()];

        for(;flag;){
            for(int a=2;d>a;a++){
                if(d==(a)||d%a==0){
                break;
                }
                if((d-1)==a){
                hold = d;
                }
            }
            d++;
            if(hold==2 || hold!=prime[i-1]){
            prime[i] = hold;
            i++;
            }
            if(i==prime.length)
            flag= false;
        }
        for(int x=0;x<prime.length;x++)
        System.out.print(prime[x]+" ");
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```